# nginx time to first byte

Tags: nginx, php, vps, optimization, linode

I running several project on one machine, below with all the info.
on nginx config if `PHP` project use fastcgi cache, `Node.js` project use `proxy_pass` , and all project use `gzip`.

I'm new to maintain the server, my problem is all project running test e.g. `http://www.webpagetest.org/` **time to first byte is so high**, I been search couple week ,and I can't find why? and wondering does these results is this machine bottleneck?  or do I miss something?  any suggestions are appreciated!!
 `domain1.com`  - `690 ms First Byte Time, 6 ms Target First Byte Time`
 `sub.domain2.com`  - `509 ms First Byte Time, 6 ms Target First Byte Time`
 `domain4.com`  - `1772 ms First Byte Time, 9 ms Target First Byte Time`

**Background info**

```
linode
  1 GB RAM
  1 CPU Core
  24 GB SSD Storage
  2 TB Transfer
  40 Gbps Network In
  125 Mbps Network Out

nginx
PHP
Node.js
PostgreSQL
```

[image: CPU - month - 2 hr avg]
[image: traffic - month - 2 hr avg]
[image: IO - month - 2 hr avg]

nginx config

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.com.access.log;
root /var/www/html/domain1.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
client_max_body_size 1G;
location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_buffers 8 32k;

# cache
fastcgi_cache domain1.com;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
}
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name sub.domain1.com www.sub.domain1.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/sub.domain1.com.access.log;
root /var/www/html/sub.domain1.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
client_max_body_size 1G;
location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_buffers 8 32k;

# cache
fastcgi_cache sub.domain1.com;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
}
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name domain2 www.domain2;
access_log /var/log/nginx/domain2.access.log;
location / {
proxy_pass http://127.00.0.1:8001/;
}
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name sub.domain2  www.sub.domain2;
access_log /var/log/nginx/sub.domain2.access.log;
location ~ ^/sitemap/(.*)$ {
root /var/www/html/sub.domain2/app/Sitemap/SitemapGz;
}
location /robots.txt {
alias /var/www/html/sub.domain2/app/robots.txt;
}
location ~ ^/(images/|javascripts/|stylesheets/|fonts) {
root /var/www/html/sub.domain2/app/assets;
access_log off;
expires max;
}
location / {
set $fixed_destination $http_destination;
if ( $http_destination ~* ^https(.*)$ )
{
set $fixed_destination http$1;
}
proxy_pass http://127.00.0.1:8002/;

proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Destination $fixed_destination;

client_max_body_size 32M;
client_body_buffer_size 512k;
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
proxy_buffer_size 4k;
proxy_buffers 4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name domain3.io www.domain3.io;
access_log /var/log/nginx/domain3.io.access.log;
location / {
proxy_pass http://127.00.0.1:8003/;
}
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name domain4.com www.domain4.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/domain4.com.access.log;
root /var/www/html/domain4.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
client_max_body_size 1G;

location ~ ^/sitemap/(.*)$ {
root /var/www/html/domain4.com/app/Sitemap/SitemapGz;
}
location /robots.txt {
alias /var/www/html/domain4.com/app/robots.txt;
}
location ~ ^/(images/|javascripts/|stylesheets/|fonts) {
root /var/www/html/domain4.com/app/assets;
access_log off;
expires max;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_buffers 8 32k;

# cache
fastcgi_cache domain4.com;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
}
}
```

free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           987        721        266          3         19        124
-/+ buffers/cache:        577        409 
Swap:          255        133        122
```

ps aux --sort -rss | head
(user apache is nginx because I used to install apache on this machine but now stop the service)

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
apache   24505  5.2 13.1 372208 132552 ?       R    06:33   1:26 php-fpm: pool www            
apache   24502  4.8 12.5 366332 126748 ?       R    06:33   1:20 php-fpm: pool www            
root     15490  0.2 11.6 1036476 117820 ?      Ssl  Sep30   1:30 node /var/www/html/sub.domain4.com/app/app.js                                                                                                     
root     11488  0.0  3.3 905404 34336 ?        Ssl  Sep15  16:21 PM2 v0.14.7: God Daemon                                                     
apache   24866  7.0  3.0 265504 30448 ?        S    06:56   0:18 php-fpm: pool www            
apache   25247  7.3  2.6 262260 26976 ?        S    06:58   0:10 php-fpm: pool www            
apache   25449  7.1  2.3 259408 24260 ?        S    06:58   0:07 php-fpm: pool www            
mongod    3584  0.9  1.9 653472 19588 ?        Sl   Sep07 317:26 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
root      2637  0.1  1.0 431044 11096 ?        Sl   Sep07  56:31 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -s /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock -p /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid -x -b
```

df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda        24G  3.3G   20G  15% /
tmpfs           492M  108K  492M   1% /dev/shm
```

apache stop already

sudo lsof -nPi | grep ":80 (LISTEN)"

```
nginx     15280     root   12u  IPv4  91859687      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     15282    nginx   12u  IPv4  91859687      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

service httpd status

```
httpd is stopped
```

**UPDATE**

After I upgrade to 2GB RAM 2 CPU Cores, when I ping the domain or use http://www.webpagetest.org test again both faster, but in the report `Target First Byte Time` become much higher, what is it and why?

free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1991        744       1246         12         78        229
-/+ buffers/cache:        436       1554 
Swap:          255          0        255
```

ps aux --sort -rss | head

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      2732  0.5  6.7 1069664 136836 ?      Ssl  09:46   0:07 node /var/www/html/domain/app/app.js                                                                                                     
mongod    2598  0.4  3.4 649400 69728 ?        Sl   09:43   0:06 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
root      2706  0.1  2.2 978924 45424 ?        Ssl  09:45   0:02 PM2 v0.14.7: God Daemon                                                     
apache    5458  6.1  1.7 268540 35964 ?        S    10:03   0:16 php-fpm: pool www            
apache    5518  6.6  1.7 267752 35184 ?        S    10:03   0:16 php-fpm: pool www            
apache    5332  6.8  1.7 267604 35100 ?        S    10:02   0:20 php-fpm: pool www            
apache    5330  6.8  1.6 267420 34568 ?        S    10:02   0:20 php-fpm: pool www            
apache    5493  7.1  1.6 266028 33484 ?        S    10:03   0:18 php-fpm: pool www            
postgres  2557  0.3  0.9 324640 19812 ?        S    09:43   0:04 /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postmaster -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data
```

df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda        24G  2.3G   21G  10% /
tmpfs           994M  108K  994M   1% /dev/shm
```

`domain1.com`  - `108 ms First Byte Time, 108 ms Target First Byte Time`
 `sub.domain2.com`  - `514 ms First Byte Time,   Target First Byte Time`
 `domain4.com`  - `124 ms First Byte Time, 114 ms Target First Byte Time`

Comment: Post your memory usage stats.

Comment: @EEAA I update in question. I don't have install any monitor app, is that enough info?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is to double the RAM of your server. There is very little free, which means that very little data is able to be cached in RAM. This means that nearly all disk reads have to hit your disk, which slows down both reads and writes.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Sometimes I will get notice from linode : `Your Linode,  has exceeded the notification threshold (10000) for disk io rate by averaging 11605.63 for the last 2 hours.` Does that related memory?     if I upgrade to next level is `2 GB RAM, 2 CPU Cores` is this better enough to get under 0.4 sec?

Comment: The only way to know is to try it. If that doesn't help, then you'll need to collect more data to see what the source of all that IO is.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try now and see what happen, will be back to update

Comment: I been upgrade to `2 GB RAM, 2 CPU Cores` and I update the test result in question , so much efficient. I'm wondering whats different `Target First Byte Time`, `First Byte Time`. becuase after I upgrade, now the `Target First Byte Time` much higher